# Can I turn a Windows machine into an AirPlay destination?

Tags: windows, airplay, streaming

Is there software available that'll make a Windows PC running XP appear as an AirPlay destination in my Mac's iTunes? I'd like to be able to stream audio from my Macs to a Windows machine I use as my home theater PC that's connected to my stereo.

Comment: Right now, no. Though I am sure there will be. AirPlay is still new and it will take a bit of time.

Comment: This is basically something Apple do not want you to do, when you can buy an AppleTV for it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/win/) allows you to AirPlay audio and video **from** iOS **to** Windows. It claims to support iOS 9 now also (note I personally haven't tested the iOS 9 support yet).

Reflector installs an app that acts as an AirPlay and Google Cast receiver. The app is available for Windows, Mac, Android, or Amazon Fire. Since Reflector supports receiving both AirPlay and Google Cast it can receive audio/video from iOS or Android.

It's from Squirrels, the same company that makes the excellent [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) app (which allows you send AirPlay audio and video **from** Windows and Mac **to** AirPlay and Google Cast).

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to stream audio, try Airfoil Speakers, part of [Airfoil for Windows](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/)

Comment: Here is the [AirFoil Speakers link](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) and that is almost what I'm looking for. You have to be running AirFoil on the Mac (or another PC) to send audio to the AirFoil Speakers program. I'd like to not have to buy AirFoil for Mac. This is definitely the closest I've seen to a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fast and simple open source program that works very well:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/shairport4w/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [AirMedia Player for Windows](http://apogeorgiadis.blogspot.com/p/airmediaplayer-for-windows.html) is made to let you do this from at least an iOS device, probably iTunes as well.

Comment: whoa. That's some buggy software! I'll keep an eye on it, but for now it's unusable.

Comment: Not surprised since its a new tech. I have not used it, just saw it in my RSS feeds the other day.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this article](http://compixels.com/8974/enable-airplay-on-windows-pc-to-wirelessly-stream-audio-video-from-ios-devices) with a couple of solutions.

My favorite option is the Shareport. Another option not yet mentioned could be to share your iTunes library with your windows PC. See [this page](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2012/04/share-your-itunes-library-with-others-by-using-home-sharing.html) for more details.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

The WiFi2HiFi app is what you are looking for. It can stream audio from any computer program to the iPhone: http://www.wifi2hifi.com

Comment: But that's *not* what I'm looking for. Not at all. I want to stream *to* iTunes running on a *Windows PC*. Not to my iPhone.

Comment: iTunes is as far as I know not capable of being an Airplay _client_.

Comment: This is sending data the wrong direction.

Answer (score -3):

Use airparrot to stream your windows screen to ur apple tv.
http://airparrot.com

Comment: AirParrot is awesome but it takes what's on windows and plays it to Apple TV. this question covers sending media to the PC as opposed to off the PC.